# Case When Statement Age not calculating when Archived_Date is NULL and returning NULL value in Age column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CASE    
    WHEN Isconverted = 'TRUE'    THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Task_CreatedDate, OPP.CreatedDate)
    WHEN Isconverted = 'FALSE'   THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Task_CreatedDate, A.Archived_Date)
    WHEN A.Archived_Date IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Task_CreatedDate, GETDATE())
    ELSE 'NULL'
END AS 'Age'
```

**
Above case when statement is not calculating third line when Archive_Date is null I need the age column to be populated with current date - Task_CreatedDate
**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
(CASE WHEN Isconverted = 'TRUE'
      THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Task_CreatedDate, OPP.CreatedDate)
      ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, Task_CreatedDate, COALESCE(A.Archived_Date, GETDATE()))
 END) AS Age
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume for the cases that A.Archived_Date IS NULL, Isconverted is either true or false , so one of first two cases will be picked always.

so if that is a priority over those you need to put it as the first case :

```
CASE    
    WHEN A.Archived_Date IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Task_CreatedDate, GETDATE())
    WHEN Isconverted = 'TRUE'    THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Task_CreatedDate, OPP.CreatedDate)
    WHEN Isconverted = 'FALSE'   THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Task_CreatedDate, A.Archived_Date)
    ELSE 'NULL'
END AS 'Age'
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, you're correct. However I need A.Archived_Date IS NULL to be followed after the above 2 statements are completed. As the Age is not being calculated for all the records in the first 2 case when statement; thus for remaining I want it to be calculated from Archived_Date. If I move Archived_Date to the first row then I would not get desired result.

Comment: @Vishal then see gordon answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by placing the `CASE` expression inside the `DATEDIFF()` function, where you can use `COALESCE()` to check if `A.Archived_Date` is `NULL`:

```
DATEDIFF(
  DAY, 
  Task_CreatedDate, 
  CASE WHEN Isconverted = 'TRUE' THEN OPP.CreatedDate ELSE COALESCE(A.Archived_Date, GETDATE()) END
) AS Age
```